# UDP: using same port number on both sides of network for sending and receiving asyncronously

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, udp, client-server, ports

Im in the process of creating two applications that will communicate over UDP. Both applications will need to send and retrieve data asynchronously.

My question is: Should i define separate ports to listen and send on or can both applications send and receive on the same port?

Example:
App1 send on port 6060<-----------> App 2 listens on 6060
App1 listens on port 6060 <---------> App2 sends on 6060

or

App1 send on port 6060<------------> App 2 listens on 6060
App1 listens on port 7070 <----------> App2 sends on 7070

Thanks

Comment: Just note. For this scheme (peer-to-peer connection) you either need at least one public IP address (on app1 or app2) or you need some NAT traversal mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to waste a port in this way. UDP is full duplex; sockets are full duplex; and sending back to the port of origin is much easier than sending to a different port, which has to be configured at both ends.

Comment: also, having the same port helps if there's a stateful firewall in between